# How to convert multiple files encoded in UTF-8-BOM to ANSI?

Tags: powershell, encoding, unicode, ansi

I'm trying to convert multiple files that are encoded in UTF-8-BOM back to ANSI.

I found out that with Powershell using this command:

```
PS> get-item c:\temp\utf8\*.* | foreach-object {get-content -Encoding utf8BOM $_ | out-file ("c:\temp\ansi\" + $_.Name) -encoding default}
```

It is working, but the problem is that it does not support ISO-8859-2.

Characters like `ă` or `â` are displayed correctly, but characters like `ţ` or `ş` are displayed as questions marks.

I would like the output to be correct in both cases.
If Powershell it's not the solution, what else do you guys recommend ?

Comment: Did you tell it to use ISO-8859-2 or do you expect it to guess for every file?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a letter that is encoded in UTF-8-BOM but is not included in ANSI, the conversion will fail.
Are you aware that ANSI codes fit into one byte where UTF-8 can use up to four bytes?

1.3.2021 0:11 MEZ:

Your conversion from UTF-8 to ANSI can only work if the letters in UTF8 used are part of ANSI.
Look here: "Neutral chess king"
https://www.utf8-zeichentabelle.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl

There is no ANSI code for this UTF letter.

Comment: I know a software that is able to encode UTF-8-BOM to ANSI and save all the characters with no issues , but is lacking batch mode. I didin't know what you said about ANSI codes , I only know that one particular software is able to change and I was looking for something to work faster with.